# Making responsive to non responsive

Tags: html, css

I took a template which is responsive, but i want it to make it non reponsive from all devices.

I tried various sources , but what i get is to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

similar to that

I just tried the above way..

How can I do this

Comment: Need more code to give an accurate assessment. If it is responsive using media queries it will be a lot more extensive. If it uses percentage-based widths, you should be able to change the html or body element and fix it. Need more info.

Comment: YHere is my URL I am not sure about media queries

Comment: http://dindca.com/scott/w/te/

Comment: *why* do you want to do this? o.O

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is a flexible and responsive layout. It uses a combination of Media Queries, Percentage Widths, and Flexible-Box elements. It will be fairly difficult to effectively restyle that page. You will need to essentially strip out all media queries (located in responsive.css) and change the outer-most elements to fixed widths. (For example change body to width: 1200x or whatever suits you)  It will be tedious, but you will need to look at every width in your code. Hope this helps!